# How can I recover my IOTA balance?

Tags: wallet, address, iota-recovery

I transferred iota from Bitfinex to my wallet in October. And at first the wallet displayed the balance but then it went to zero. How can I troubleshoot/recover my balance?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but still no Balance only the 10Mi default one, I have downloaded the last version of your light wallet 2.5.7, followed the instructions on this page. any other instructions? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Get the latest wallet: https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/releases

2) Try using different Nodes - Tools -> Edit Node Configuration Min Weight Magnitude should always be 14 or above. Curl Implementation can be tried both, Webgl 2 and CCurl

3) Generate a few address and re-attach them to tangle until your full balance shows up

Comment: how many times did you re-attach to the tangle?

Comment: Roughly 5 times to get the entire balance

Comment: that's better than me...i've reattached over 20 times and still 0 balance.

Comment: I was worried and kept putting it off because of the general sentiment regarding the difficulty level. I reattached to the tangle twice and my entire balance showed. The process was actually much easier than I thought (it turns out I was using an outdated version of the wallet).