# Missing from Wallet

Tags: wallet

I have just logged onto my wallet, which I haven't used for a while. I log on fine with my seed but it shows a 0 balance when I should have 99 in there. No withdrawals are shown. Please can you help.

Comment: Your question is answered here!
https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/128/how-can-i-recover-my-iota-balance?rq=1

Comment: Or in case you are using the Trinity desktop wallet, it has built-in Snapshot Recovery feature so you don't have to do the attaching for each address manually.